# аннотация значений на графике Google Chart

Tags: google-chart

При выводе графика ColumnChart если значение находится на границе оси Y, то аннотация выводится внутри столбца.
Как сделать чтобы выводилось всегда сверху?
https://jsfiddle.net/dkostin/yopeymk5/

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawColColors);

function drawColColors() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Time of Day');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Motivation Level');
  data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
  data.addColumn('number', 'Energy Level');
  data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});

  data.addRows([
    ['a', 8, '8', 5.25, '5.25'],
    ['b', 9, '9', 7.5, '7.5'],
    ['c', 10, '10', 10, '10'],
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Motivation and Energy Level Throughout the Day',
    colors: ['#9575cd', '#33ac71'],
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Time of Day',
      format: 'h:mm a',
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Rating (scale of 1-10)'
    },
    annotations: {
      'alwaysOutside': true
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```